# Do I need a separate Model/Controller for each scenario, or can I reuse a single Model/Controller for multiple scenarios?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My Home Model/View/Controller (which configures the initial state of the page) is working fine.

I also, though, need to respond to changes the user makes on the page (selecting an option from a select, checking a checkbox, etc.), and have not got that to work yet.

Maybe the reason I'm having problems is that I'm trying to reuse my "Home" model, which contains not only what I need for page initialization, but some other things as well. For example, my model:

```
public class HomeModel
{
    public DataTable Units { get; set; }
    public DataTable Reports { get; set; }
    public DataTable UnitReportPairEmailVals { get; set; }
    public DataTable UnitReportPairGenerateVals { get; set; }
    . . .
}
```

...contains things the page needs at first ("Units"and "Reports" and the things represented by the ellipsis dots), but also things only needed later (the other two shown).

I'm wondering if at least part of my problem with getting this data back (via an Ajax call to another method in HomeController) is because I should be using a separate Model and Controller for the Ajax call.

So I'm wondering: is Model/Controller proliferation a code smell/anti-pattern, or necessary? Should I create another Model like:

```
public class AJAXModel
{
    public DataTable UnitReportPairEmailVals { get; set; }
}
```

...and a corresponding separate Controller for it?

If I have a complex Model, which is used in various scenarios, it seems that every time I pass a model back as the return value (result) of an Action, a lot of superfluous/unpopulated things will also be passed back (only the members that I'm interested in at the time being populated in the Controller, thus passing back a lot of empty/null members).

So my question is, should I create spearate Models/Controllers for each "use case", or is it okay - or even better - to combine a bunch of things into one Model/Controller pair?

Comment: A common approach is to make a few specific `ViewModel` objects to pass to your client - and then maybe use an auto-mapper to map the common-but-complex `Model` to a scenario-specific `ViewModel`. I see no reason to make new `Controller` or `Model` classes in your case.

Comment: If you are not changing the View, why would you think about creating another Controller? Don't you mean another **Action** in your existing Controller?

Comment: Reusing a composite model seems more of an anti-pattern than proliferation of models.  Also, I'm a little skeptical of using `DataTable` in a model.

Comment: @cFrozenDeath: I don't know if you would consider this changing the view, but the end result will be to alter what the user sees - specifically, to add some saved email addresses to some input textboxes.

Comment: @stephen.vakil: Using the DataTables works fine in the initial populating of the page. I'm open to a better methodology, though.

Comment: @Clay: (I almost feel like I'm talking to myself) - it sounds like you're talking MVVM, whereas I'm using MVC.

Comment: Well...MVC is the product, but MVVM is the technique (for the purposes of this discussion)...and it's perfect valid for your scenario. Typically, your `ViewModels` would be plain ol' CLR types - not EF or data-backed in any way.

Comment: There's a modest auto-mapper in the box with MVC 6 - makes this approach pretty straightforward - as long as your property names line up between `Models` and `ViewModels`. Older versions...I dunno...but I know there are good auto-mappers out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no compelling reason to limit a `Model` to a single `Controller` or to expect that a `Controller` has only one `Model`. You could write your entire app in a single `Controller` (really bad idea, by the way).

Generally, the division is a logical one...a bunch of actions that talk to the same set of `Models` in one controller. It's more to keep your brain from melting when you open the source file as anything else.

You often have multiple `Views` and they tend to mach name-for-name with the `Actions` in your controller...but this isn't strictly enforced.

When you feel like you're getting more data in the `View` than necessary, this can be simplified by mapping the `Model` to a `ViewModel` to simplify the code in the `View`. Yes, this is MVVM...and again...the brain hurts less dealing with the simpler object in the `View`.

You can manually map the object in your `Controller`, or you can use an auto-mapper to do it. There are a number to choose from...and they make the MVVM a simpler thing to do. You don't necessarily *need* one. They're just helpful.

Comment: I wonder how long it will be until "Florida Hill Country"* becomes the Island of Florida. *BTW, although I have been to St. Augustine, no I did know that any part of Florida was not flatter than the proverbial flapjack.

Comment: Indeed - scary propositions all around. We're at 110'...good for at least another 10 yrs?